# Java: Split a string with less code in method

Tags: java, split

I have now some inputs like this pattern:

> org.apache.commons.fileupload,version=1.2.1,org.apache.commons.fileuplo>ad.disk,version=3.0.0,org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet,version=1.2>.1,org.apache.commons.fileupload.util,version=1.2.1,org.apache.commons.>io,version=1.4.0,org.apache.commons.io.filefilter,version=1.4.0,org.apa>che.commons.io.output,version=1.4.0,org.apache.felix.inventory,version=>1.0.0,org.apache.felix.webconsole,version=3.3.0,org.apache.felix.webcon>sole.bundleinfo,version=1.0.0,org.apache.felix.webconsole.i18n,version=>1.0.0]
>   attributes[0]: org.apache.commons.fileupload

And I need to split it and store it in table  or list like this:

where : (Exemple)

```
 String[] attributes = inputs.split();
 attributes[0]: org.apache.commons.fileupload,version=1.2.0
 attributes[1]: org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk,version=3.0.0

  .....
```

I tried with some code:

```
attributes = input.split("((,version=)*([0-9],))");
```

```
but i got: 
attributes[0]: org.apache.commons.fileupload,version=1.2.
attributes[1]: org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk,version=3.0.
```

Where the last digits of version=1.2.X is always missing !

I hope someone if can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this particular stack trace, the best pattern for splitting would be this:

```
,(?=(?:org|com)\\.)
```

That is, split on the final comma in each line of the stack trace.

```
String[] parts = text.split(",(?=(?:org|com)\\.)");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Output:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload,version=1.2.1
org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk,version=3.0.0
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet,version=1.2.1
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util,version=1.2.1
org.apache.commons.io,version=1.4.0
org.apache.commons.io.filefilter,version=1.4.0
org.apache.commons.io.output,version=1.4.0
org.apache.felix.inventory,version=>1.0.0
org.apache.felix.webconsole,version=3.3.0
org.apache.felix.webconsole.bundleinfo,version=1.0.0
org.apache.felix.webconsole.i18n,version=>1.0.0] attributes[0]:org.apache.commons.fileupload
```

Regarding what happens when the stack trace mentioned some other package, we can add another prefix to the alternation.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a good idea to think for I didn't saw it before .. but unfortunately it's just a special input and normally we will not have this kind of input  "org\\.apache", it could be anything lik org.xxx.yyyy :/ ..

Comment: Not bad, but you are assuming that all his stacktraces will be based on apache dependencies, which might not be the best approach

Comment: Then generalize to packages starting with `com` or `org`, followed by a dot.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, This seems work in better way, I will marked solved by ur answer thank for u all

Answer (score 0):

Try with the regex below, although you closed it already:

```
(([a-zA-Z.0-9]*,version=>?[0-9.]*)|[a-zA-Z.0-9]*),?
```